# Define a JPA column as LOB based on database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lob

In our Spring application we use Spring JPA. We've defined an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Cat{
    // ....

    //@Lob <-- only if OracleDB is used
    @Column
    private String description;
}
```

The application can be used with different databases. Since most of the databases are able to handle even large texts within a `VARCHAR` column we decided to use just a default `VARCHAR` column to store the description.

But now a customer want's to use his Oracle database. Since there is a *crazy* length restriction on `VARCHAR` type we have to use a `CLOB` in the database scheme.

Now the main question is if there is a possibility to mark the relevant fields in the JPA entities as Lob but **only if Oracle dialect is used** at runtime.

Comment: Could you provide the list of databases that your app uses.

Comment: Postgres in different versions, H2 and Oracle (new). We also have some AWS databases in use (don't now the exact name).

Comment: By the way, the length of oracle `VARCHAR2` can be extended to the `32767` byte limit by enabling the `MAX_STRING_SIZE` [property](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html).